# Hyperledger Compose REST API authentication with apigee

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am using apigee oauth2 service to run the Hyperledger Composer REST api in multliuser mode. https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-multiuser.html

In the above link, I gone thru the github oauth authentication steps (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html), but wanted to use apigee.

How can I construct COMPOSER_PROVIDERS environment variable object literal specific to apigee? What kind of [passportjs](http://www.passportjs.org/) module need to use?

Answer (score 0):

the supported authentication strategies for Composer REST server can be found at http://www.passportjs.org/packages/ (search OAUTH2). I did not see apigee there (albeit it uses Node.js `passport` and `passport-oauth2` modules to implement its OAuth 2.0 authorization flow).

Furthermore, we do have an OAUTH2 tutorial - using Google OAUTH2.0 strategy that you can check out -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest

Comment: True. As composer uses loopback to generate rest api, it has no support of oauth2 passport package implementation for APIGEE lying behind corporate proxy.